# nio.channels.FileChannel.open threw NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, nio

I have a microservice that is working fine most of the times. Recently it threw a `NoSuchFileException` exception when it was opening a file to write:

```
    FileChannel.open(Paths.get("/tmp/somethingirrelevant"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

I don't understand why it can throw such exception, considering that it will create a new one if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One scenario where `NoSuchFileException` is thrown is when an intermediate path component does not exist:

```
FileChannel.open(Paths.get("/tmp/does/not/exist"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

The CREATE option only creates the file, it does not create the directories that should contain the file.